# Replacing scalar with template fails

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, eigen, eigen3

I'm trying to write a function that takes an Eigen::Matrix from either type double or float. This function works fine for floats:

```
Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 4> foo(const Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 4> &T)
{
   Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 4> result;
   result.block<3,3>(0,0) = T.block<3,3>(0,0).transpose();
   return result;
}
```

However, as soon as I make the "float" a template:

```
template <typename Scalar>
inline Eigen::Matrix<Scalar, 4, 4> foo(const Eigen::Matrix<Scalar, 4, 4> &T)
{
   Eigen::Matrix<Scalar, 4, 4> result;
   result.block<3,3>(0,0) = T.block<3,3>(0,0).transpose();
   return result;
}
```

I get this error with gcc 4.9.1 on linux:

> .../utils.hpp: In function 'Eigen::Matrix
>   core::math::foo(const Eigen::Matrix&)':
>   .../utils.hpp:77:47: error: request for member 'transpose' in '(0,
>   0)', which is of non-class type 'int'
>       result.block<3,3>(0,0) = T.block<3,3>(0,0).transpose();

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the function is template some calls are dependent of template and so you have to add some `template` keyword, try:

```
template <typename Scalar>
inline Eigen::Matrix<Scalar, 4, 4> foo(const Eigen::Matrix<Scalar, 4, 4> &T)
{
   Eigen::Matrix<Scalar, 4, 4> result;
   result.template block<3,3>(0,0) = T.template block<3,3>(0,0).transpose();
   return result;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that works! Although I'm not sure I understand what exactly happens, and what "template block" does... could you explain in detail or give me some pointer to an explanation?

Comment: You may look at [where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)